# How can i use longs as key in glib hash table?

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

in `g_hash_table_new(HashFunc hash_func, GEqualFunc key_equal_func)`

HashFunc they have this types:

- `g_direct_hash()`
- `g_int_hash()`
- `g_int64_hash()`
- `g_double_hash()`
- `g_str_hash()`

GEqualFunc they have this types:

- `g_direct_equal()`
- `g_int_equal()`
- `g_int64_equal()`
- `g_double_equal()`
- `g_str_equal()`

Which type can i use to have a key that is a long and a value that is a pointer for a struct that i have defined?

Comment: Why not use a `gconstpointer` as the manual says?

Comment: turning my long in the `gconstpointer`?

Comment: Assuming you build for a system where a pointer is at least as many bits as a long, yes, you can cast it and use `g_direct_*`. Otherwise: do not use `long` but either `int` or `int64_t` for your values and pass pointers to them to `g_int_*` or `g_int64_*`

Comment: as @marcolz says, Why use long? long is either the same of int or bigger (depending on compilation target), so if you do not use int I assume is because you know long may be bigger than int, which is very likely int64_t. Knowing this, follow marcolz instructions..

Comment: In my .h file i can `#define G_MININT64 LONG_MIN` and `#define G_MAXINT64 LONG_MAX` and then the int64 will be equal to a Long

Comment: No it won't. You'll just be telling glib it is (kind of…), that doesn't make it so, and it's a great way to break software. What matters is really `sizeof(long)` vs. `sizeof(void*)`, and that's determined by the platform not glib.  If `sizeof(long) > sizeof(void*)` you need to allocate space for the long somewhere then use a *pointer* to that data as your key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing from comments:

Assuming you build for a system where a pointer is at least as many bits as a long (true on most systems), yes, you can cast it to a `gconstpointer` and use `g_direct_*`. You do build in a dependency on that fact into your code that way though.

Otherwise: do not use `long` but either `gint` or `gint64` for your values and pass pointers to them to `g_int_*` or `g_int64_*`. Using `long`, which can differ in actual size per system, in portable code is not handy anyway.

`g_direct_*` use the pointers themselves instead of the values pointed to by them.